# How do I setup multiple static IP's on multiple NIC's with one gateway?

Tags: static-ip, gateway, nic

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Currently I have this in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1 inet static
    address 198.167.16.164
    netmask 255.255.240.0
    gateway 197.167.16.254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eno2 inet static
    address 198.167.16.165
    netmask 255.255.240.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eno3 inet static
    address 198.167.16.166
    netmask 255.255.240.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eno4 inet static
    address 198.167.16.167
    netmask 255.255.240.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I can reach all these IPs from our LAN, but I can only ping the public internet with eno1 (ie. `ping -I eno1 google.com`, the other interfaces can't resolve the hostname being pinged. I feel I'm on the right track, but can't out what exactly I should do next. Hoping to use this same gateway for all of them.

After this works I'm hoping to bind docker networks to each IP.

Comment: Did you tried to add gateway line on each interfaces?

Comment: Yes I did, and it does the same thing except in that case eno4 is the only one that can ping internet.

Comment: Hum, this is a really good question, I will vote up for you, I'm very interested to see how it can be dealed with, I will also have a look on Google.

Comment: I guess I found the answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/two-interfaces-two-addresses-two-gateways

Comment: I will have to give that a try in the morning and see how it works.

Comment: The solution in the link you provided is answering the question that involves two static IP's and two separate gateways. I have 4 static IP's, but was hoping to use a single gateway. Would that mean I'd just add a single new entry in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables?

Comment: Oh, also, what's the distinction between "the IP address of the gateway" and "IP network the gateway is in" ?